# Spring Security 5 custom failureForwardUrl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 5.0.4 with Spring Boot 2.0.1

I have a working security configuration:

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/#", "/reader.html").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/app/**", "/assets/**", "/translations/**", "/vendor/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated() // everything else needs authentication
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .permitAll();
```

It works as expected: When I provide good credentials I'm logged in, it forwards me to `/index.html`. When I provide bad credentials, it forwards me back to `/login` with `?error` query param.

But, if I complete it with a custom `failureForwardUrl()` or `successForwardUrl()` for example:

```
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .successForwardUrl("/home")
    .failureForwardUrl("/login?fail=true")
    .permitAll()
```

it behaves strangely.

If I provide bad credentials, it forwards me back to `/login` without any query parameters. If I provide good credentials, then I receive a `HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed` status (`POST` to `/login`)

This configuration worked in Spring Security 4.x.

What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: sorry for writing 3 years later. did you managed to describe the interference? I'm coding the same scenario. Api with basic login and web backend using login. I always end falling back the api to the form login although they are on separate configuration classes.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that I mixed up `.failureUrl("/login?error")` with `.failureForwardUrl("/login?error")`. Facepalm.